# Difficult to find application installed in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, unity

I am new to linux, used to use windows. I am trying to convert to linux and I really love it. I am trying Ubuntu 14.10.

I have a question about how to find the installed applications easily in Linux. You know in windows, after I installed an application, I can always find it in the "all application" list. Even no, I can always try to search for its folder from the bottom.

However, I am trying two DE, Unity and Gnome 3.12, and it seems that it's more difficult to do this. For example, I've just installed Anaconda3. After installation, it does not show up in the launcher nor the "all application list". I tried to search "Anaconda" or "Spyder" but hits nothing. It looks like it's also impossible to open the file manager to show all folders in the partition on which ubuntu is installed. I can open a terminal and "cd /" and then search it? But that's text interface.

So my questions are: Are there any way to find an installed application easily. Is there something like the file manager in windows that can show all the folders in the linux partition or in the whole harddisk?

Comment: You should be able to view the whole filesystem in a graphical file manager, but that would be the worse way to find your executable. The simple way is to list the executables installed by the package (I'm sure I already saw a question about that here). But the Ubuntu package for spyder contains a .desktop file so you should have a menu entry. How did you install it ?

Comment: I downloaded the linux installer and then in the shell execute

bash Anaconda3-2.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh

Comment: The anaconda install page mentions *After the self extraction is finished, you should add the anaconda binary directory to your PATH environment variable.*. This is not a normal package installation which may be why you have trouble with it. *As all of Anaconda is contained in a single directory, uninstalling Anaconda is easy (you simply remove the entire install location directory).* so it depends on what directory you instructed the installation to use. You should be able to find that directory with your file manager.

Comment: This is a special case because Anaconda isn't packaged. If you don't use the package manager, it entirely depends on the application. The install page says it installs to `~/anaconda` (anaconda directory in your home) unless you chose another path. You'll have to create shortcuts yourself.

Comment: @Leiaz and wurtel, thank you very much for your help. I am reading the installation guide and will figure it out myself. One more question, seems that the file manger in Unity can only show my home directory only, which is /home/superuser. Is it possible to go in the file manger to go to other directories?

Comment: @wurtel Thanks! I've added it. PATH=$PATH:~/anaconda3/bin

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, or Unity, or Gnome. Looking at screenshots, I understand the confusion ... According to [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreNautilusLocationBar) you can use Ctrl+L to get a bar where you can type a path. There are also other file managers out there that didn't push the "simple user friendly interface" idea that far :)

Comment: give dmenu a try

Answer (score 0):

May you are looking for something like synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

With this application you can see all the application installed and some details.

Comment: Only for those things that are properly packaged, not installed via an installer script.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a question about how to find the installed applications easily in Linux.

After you install a package, you can see in the output of

```
dpkg -l
```

That will show all packages and their status (Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold). Not this only tells you things you installed with `dpkg` (the Debian package manager). like on Windows, if your program installs by unzipping to the desktop, nothing is going to track that.

Answer (score -1):

In the shell, `which` as in `which firefox` tells you where it is located.